# GWT-Button acting as hyperlink

Tags: gwt

I am trying to create an "Open" button which will open a new website.

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to create an event that opens a new website. 
How can I register the Hyperlink widget to this ClickEvent :

```
 Button button = new Button("Open");
 button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
          Hyperlink widget = new Hyperlink("Home Page", "Home");

             }
 });
 rootPanel.add(button, 568, 275);
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code will open the link in the current window when the button is clicked:

```
Button button = new Button("Open");
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Window.Location.assign("http://www.someurl.com");
  }
});
rootPanel.add(button);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with [hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html). You should do it with [anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) or window assign or just simple native javascript methods like that

```
Button button = new Button("Open");
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
          Window.Location.assign("new url");
```

or

```
          getURL("new url");
```

or add anchor to the panel

```
         Anchor a = new Anchor("new page", "new url");
         RootPanel.get().add(a);
     }
});
rootPanel.add(button, 568, 275);


public static native String getURL(String url)/*-{
        return $wnd.open(url, 'target=_blank')
    }-*/;
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I had problems with the `$wnd.open(url, 'target=_blank')` method in Internet Explorer 9.  Switching to `Window.Location.assign(url)` solved the problem for me.  So, that seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your event handler request a URL change, not have it add a new widget.

Do you want to open it in a new window or in the same window?

Generally speaking, you would probably want to have your click handler code use the History class or the Window class to open a different URL and/or to manipulate the browser history.

Comment: GWT is a beast...not that easy to deal with as I thought in the beginning. If I am familiar with GWT I will definitely try to use the History class