# GWT: Open link from with an iFrame in the parent window (not a new tab)

Tags: iframe, gwt, hyperlink

I've an iframe embedded in an webpage. The iFrame is a GWT webapp and I would like to open a link from within the iFrame on the parent window, i.e. the page that embeds the iframe, and neither in a new tab nor in a new window.

Therefore, I searched the net and found for instance this suggestion: [GWT-Button acting as hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703014/gwt-button-acting-as-hyperlink)

So, therfore I modified my code the following way:

```
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource() == myButton)
        getURL("http://www.example.com");
}

public static native String getURL(String url)/*-{
    return $wnd.open(url, 'target="_top"')
}-*/;
```

I also tried `target="_top"`, `target="_parent"`, `target=_top` and `target=_parent` (the two latter cases are without a surrounding `"`) since this was suggested in the different sources I found. However, each suggestions continues to open a new tab rather than opening the page in the same window.

So, what do I have to do in order to open the link in the same window?

UPDATE: I've noticed that a new tab gets opened everytime I click on the link even if i open the iframes content in it's own window, i.e. even if I do not use an iframe at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it differently:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
HTML link = new HTML("<a href=\"" + url + "\" class=\"css-styling\" target=\"_parent\">Bla bla</a>");
```

This works fine.